initramfs error Cant find block device for /boot/efi
During some upgrades after a machine was not booted for over a year, I've encountered some odd efi errors and this system isn't even using UEFI as far as I'm aware.
BIOS booting is set to legacy.  There is some reserved space from the former Windows 7 installation but the 1st partition is now a simple 260MB type ext4 doing nothing.
I've been reading up about EFI and would prefer to not switch to UEFI on this system.
grub-pc is installed but no new linux-kernel images that require initramfs to be rebuilt seem to want to compile correctly.
I've removed kernels, reinstalled grub-pc, formatted the 1st partition, mounted / unmounted it, checked grub is ok and I dont know how to fix this and been trying all day.
Here is the error from the aptitude update.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4pop2~1711143149~22.04~e0b5994) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4pop2~1711143149~22.04~e0b5994) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-105-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p3
I: (UUID=c58e5139-ba75-4fc6-9785-9de7d350b976)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
kernelstub.Config    : INFO     Looking for configuration...
kernelstub.Drive     : ERROR    Could not find a block device for the a partition. This is a critical error and we cannot continue.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.esp_fs = self.get_part_dev(self.esp_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 94, in get_part_dev
    raise NoBlockDevError('Couldn\'t find the block device for %s' % path)
kernelstub.drive.NoBlockDevError: Couldn't find the block device for /boot/efi
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-kernelstub exited with return code 174
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4pop2~1711143149~22.04~e0b5994) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4pop2~1711143149~22.04~e0b5994) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-105-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p3
I: (UUID=c58e5139-ba75-4fc6-9785-9de7d350b976)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
kernelstub.Config    : INFO     Looking for configuration...
kernelstub.Drive     : ERROR    Could not find a block device for the a partition. This is a critical error and we cannot continue.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.esp_fs = self.get_part_dev(self.esp_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 94, in get_part_dev
    raise NoBlockDevError('Couldn\'t find the block device for %s' % path)
kernelstub.drive.NoBlockDevError: Couldn't find the block device for /boot/efi
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-kernelstub exited with return code 174
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
Press Return to continue, 'q' followed by Return to quit.

$ fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKKW512G7                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2BAB67F3-034D-44DD-BCB6-4D9FC7E5383E

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 252708863 251658240   120G EFI System  <-- old Win7 EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p3 252708864 386924527 134215664    64G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 386924544 903315455 516390912 246.2G Linux filesystem

I have tried setting partition 1 to boot (esp flag also gets set) but grub-install fails.
I have tried setting partition 2 to boot (esp flag also gets set) but still grub-install fails?
$ mount 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=24538672k,nr_inodes=6134668,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=4919400k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=22664)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/qemu type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=4919396k,nr_inodes=1229849,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)

$ sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1  (also tried /dev/nvme0n1p1 & p2 but no diff)
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

The installed grub packages are:
# dpkg -l | grep grub
ii  grub-common:i386                                  2.06-2ubuntu7.2                                                   i386         GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-gfxpayload-lists                             0.7                                                               amd64        GRUB gfxpayload blacklist
ii  grub-pc                                           2.06-2ubuntu7.2                                                   amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
ii  grub-pc-bin                                       2.06-2ubuntu7.2                                                   amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS modules)
ii  grub-theme-breeze                                 5.24.4-0ubuntu1                                                   amd64        Breeze theme for GRUB 2
ii  grub2-common:i386                                 2.06-2ubuntu7.2                                                   i386         GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
ii  grub2-splashimages                                1.0.1+nmu2                                                        all          a collection of great GRUB2 splashimages
ii  grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate                          0.3.7                                                             all          GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (ubuntu-mate theme)
ii  grub2-themes-ubuntustudio                         0.5                                                               all          GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (Ubuntu Studio theme)

Prior to the updates, grub was updating the NVMe boot sequence and booting was fine.
I also tried switching grub to grub-efi but had issues where bios files were missing on the /boot/efi partition to reverted back to partition 1 being a standard ext4, not mounted and left there as reserve space.
Whats the method to resolve this or does the newer kernels force GPT disks to use EFI?
